# Cannot read property 'getWidth' of undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have below code which is defined inside a function which actually set width of parent component and do layout...this function is called from 4 places and at one place there is scenario that below error comes, you can see i have checked for undefined but still it is going inside this IF and i get error :( please help identify issue

Ext Js 3.4.2

**ERROR**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getWidth' of undefined

**CODE**

```
if((typeof Ext.getCmp("cmp1") !== 'undefined') && (typeof Ext.getCmp("cmp2") !== 'undefined')){
    Ext.getCmp("cmp1").setWidth(Ext.getCmp("cmp2").getWidth()-2);
    Ext.getCmp("cmp1").doLayout();
    }else{
         //Call self again in 3 sec once render
         //setTimeout("doLayoutofcustomPanel()", 3000);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I able to figure out issue actually component was created but element (EL) was not present initially so it able to cross my IF check I need to put check as below to ensure element is present for which I need to fetch width. This worked fine

```
typeof Ext.getCmp("cmp2").el !== 'undefined'
```

I am using ExtJs 3.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of ExtJs you are using, but its better to use [itemId](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-itemId)

> itemId is scoped locally to the container -- avoiding potential
> conflicts with Ext.ComponentManager which requires a unique id

and then [query](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery-method-query) to get it.